# Why can't I loop through a custom post type and category in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

so I'm trying to output the names of posts that are a custom post type of service and a particular category.

However the code I'm using is outputting the categories of all post types

```
    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'service',
                    'cat' => $cat
                );

                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($query);
                echo '</pre>';

            ?>

            <div id="subCatBox">
                <ul id="subCatlist" class="list">

                    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is the output of the queried object

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => service
        [cat] => 4
    )

[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => any
        [cat] => 4
        [error] =>
```

I can't understand why in query the post_type is service but then in the query_vars its any. Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: try get_the_category( int $id = false ) to get the post categories.

Comment: I'm already getting the category like this $cat = get_the_category()[0]->cat_ID;

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Just in case this helps anyone else I used category__in instead of cat

```
 $query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category__in' => $cat
 ));
```